# Dell is nowhere mentioning DVB-T for Dell Studio XPS 16

Tags: dell-xps, dvb-t

The web is full of reviews mentioning that the Dell Studio XPS 16 can be bought with an integrated DBV-T receiver. But I can not find a single place across the whole Dell website stating just that, nor can I choose a DVB-T receiver when configuring the Dell Studio XPS 16. Am I missing something? Before I buy I would like to have the proof that I get one with integrated DVB-T!

UPDATE: I **can** download a driver called "WinTV v7 TV Player Application software for Dell Digital TV Receiver ATSC-01" in drivers section for the Dell Studio XPS 16. So there must be something like that. What a mystery! Maybe DVB-T went away and the download is only there to support older notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious question: Have you tried contacting Dell order support?

Comment: "This is not offered in Germany anymore". Now what?

Comment: Buy a different laptop or buy a separate tv tuner.